# How to fix a round error in R when filling a matrix?

Tags: r

I have following matrices:

```
mat <- matrix(rnorm(10801),1,length(seq(0,30,(1/360))))

colnames(mat) <- seq(0,30, by = 1/360)

mat2 <- matrix(0L,1,100)
for(j in 1 : 100 ){
mat2[,j] <- round(runif(1,0,10800),0)/360
}
```

Now I would like to fill the third matrix:

```
mat3 <- matrix(0L,1,100)

for(i in 1:100){
  mat3[1,i] <- mat[1,colnames(mat) == mat2[1,i]]
}
```

As you can see I try to fill the third matrix with the values from the first matrix at the position where the column name is equal to the value in the 2nd matrix. The Code works, but sometimes there is an error: replacement has length zero. That's the case because the column has the "name" = 9.84444445 and the value of the 2nd matrix has a value of 9.844444 without the 5 at the end. I tried options(digits = 5) and round, but it still doesn't work.
I can't use set.seed to fix a working 2nd matrix, because the R-Code is actually in another for loop which runs the code multiple times.

Can someone help me? Thanks!

Comment: It seems to work in most cases. The only thing you might try is to round the numbers for both `colnames(mat)` and the values of `mat2` to 2 decimals and convert them to character. Then you could be sure to have a corresponding value for each value in mat2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to be sure that the numbers are being rounded correctly when truncating digits. The safest way to do this is probably to convert to integers by multiplying by, say, 10^5 and taking the `floor` of the result. This will ensure equality of digits to the 4th decimal place.

```r
matnames <- floor(as.numeric(colnames(mat)) * 1e5)
for(i in 1:100){
  
  mat3[1,i] <- mat[1, matnames == floor(mat2[1, i] * 1e5)]
}
```